# Echo MySQL table data as HTML

Tags: php, mysql

The following echoes an article title and a table value that is a URL:

```
$query="SELECT a.nid, a.title, b.entity_id, b.body_value
FROM node a, field_data_body b
WHERE a.nid = b.entity_id LIMIT $selected_row, 1;";
$result=$conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["title"];
    echo $row["body_value"];

 }
?>
```

It all works as expected, but I'd like the body_value field to be returned as a hyperlink. How would I best go about accomplishing this?

I tried something to the effect of:

```
echo "<a href=\"$row[...]\">$row[...]</a>";
```

which, predictably, did not work since I suppose the echo'd bit was a little more complicated than just a PHP variable, but I was unsure of how to echo this data while using it with this HTML tag. A couple other variations were unsuccessful, so I assume I'm simply going about this the wrong way.

Comment: SHow what you actually tried, not `...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to write it:

```
echo "<a href='$row[body_value]'>$row[title]</a>";

echo "<a href='{$row['body_value']}'>{$row['title']}</a>";

echo "<a href='" . $row['body_value'] . "'>" . $row['title'] . "}</a>";
```

Each has their proponents, it's just a matter of preference.

Notice that HTML allows either `'` or `"` quoting around attribute values, so you don't need to use backslash -- just use a different quote than the one you used for the PHP string.

Comment: Thank you. `echo "<a href='$row[body_value]'>$row[title]</a>";` was spot-on; I didn't realize I could alternate the quotations.

Comment: Aren't there examples in the PHP manual section on strings that show how to do variable interpolation like this?

Comment: Admittedly, I wasn't sure how to articulate what exactly I was looking for, but I didn't find any examples that matched this circumstance (where table data was being echoed for this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this format... PHP array elements inside quotes should be surrounded by curly brackets.

```
echo "<a href='{$row[...]}'>{$row[...]}</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
  echo $row["body_value"];
```

with this:

```
  echo "<a href=\"your URL\">".$row["body_value"]."</a>";
```

or this, if the body_value is the href

```
  echo "<a href=\"".$row["body_value"]."\"> Your text Here </a>";
```